# MS bot framework, identify connected client support Card Actions and Hero Card

Tags: botframework

How can identify that connected client supports Card Action and Hero Card? If there is any way I can use Card Action against channel specific API call.

This feature is specially required to identify request is coming from Skype or Skype Web (Developer version)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to distinguish between the Skype desktop client and the web client but they should have feature parity with the new release.